# PyTorch Error while building CNN: "1only batches of spatial targets supported (3D tensors) but got targets of size: : [1, 2, 64, 64]"

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I want to build a CNN like the one in this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.08511 (https://richzhang.github.io/colorization/ ).
As data I got images from the LAB - color space. I wrote a data loader for these l and a, b values and give the l values as input to my Neural Network and the a, b values as label.
I get an error "1only batches of spatial targets supported (3D tensors) but got targets of size: : [1, 2, 64, 64]" in the criterion loss function.
There is a problem with what I am inserting as "label" into the criterion() method. But the dimensions of the label seem right to me: [1, 2, 64, 64] --> [batch_size, in_channels (a,b), width, heigth].
I set the batch_size to 1 to just see if it's working. I tried to just cut of the batch_size dimension using pytorch.squeeze(), but it didn't work. I don't understand why I can't put in a vector of this shape and size to the criterion() function. Any help is appreciated! My code is below:

```
#importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from numpy import random
# for creating validation set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# PyTorch libraries and modules
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchvision import transforms
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torch.nn import Linear, ReLU, CrossEntropyLoss, Sequential, Conv2d, MaxPool2d, Module, Softmax, BatchNorm2d, Dropout
from torch.optim import Adam, SGD
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from torchvision import datasets
from torch.utils.data.sampler import SubsetRandomSampler

from typing import Any, Tuple


# set device
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

# define local paths
L_path = 'l/gray_scale.npy'
ab1_path = 'ab/ab/ab1.npy'
ab2_path = 'ab/ab/ab2.npy'
ab3_path = 'ab/ab/ab3.npy'

image_size = 64


class ColorDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, transformations=None, seed=42) -> None:
        if transformations is None:
            self.transformations = transforms.Compose([
                transforms.ToPILImage(),
                transforms.Resize(image_size),
                transforms.ToTensor()
            ])
        else:
            self.transformations = transformations
        self.seed = seed
        self.L = np.load(L_path)
        self.L = np.expand_dims(self.L, -1)
        # self.L = self.L.transpose((0, 3, 1, 2))
        self.ab = np.concatenate([
            np.load(ab1_path),
            np.load(ab2_path),
            np.load(ab3_path)
        ], axis=0)
        # self.ab = self.ab.transpose((0, 3, 1, 2))
        print("All inputs loaded")

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self.L)

    def __getitem__(self, index: int) -> Tuple[Any, Any]:
        random.seed(self.seed)
        L = self.transformations(self.L[index])
        random.seed(self.seed)
        ab = self.transformations(self.ab[index])
        return L, ab


# initialize dataset
dataset = ColorDataset()
dataset_size = len(dataset)

# set relative test size (for split)
test_size = 0.3

indices = list(range(dataset_size))
np.random.shuffle(indices)
split = int(np.floor(test_size * dataset_size))
train_index, test_index = indices[split:], indices[:split]

train_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(train_index)
test_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(test_index)

# set batch size
batch_size = 1

train_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, sampler=train_sampler, num_workers=0)
test_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, sampler=test_sampler, num_workers=0)


# Network
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1_1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 64, 1)
        self.conv1_2 = nn.Conv2d(64, 64, 1)
        self.batch_norm_1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(64) 
        self.conv2_1 = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, 1, 2)
        self.conv2_2 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, 1)
        self.batch_norm_2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(128) 
        self.conv3_1 = nn.Conv2d(128, 256, 1, 2)
        self.conv3_2 = nn.Conv2d(256, 256, 1)
        self.conv3_3 = nn.Conv2d(256, 256, 1)
        self.batch_norm_3 = nn.BatchNorm2d(256)
        self.conv4_1 = nn.Conv2d(256, 512, 1, 2)
        self.conv4_2 = nn.Conv2d(512, 512, 1)
        self.conv4_3 = nn.Conv2d(512, 512, 1)
        self.batch_norm_4 = nn.BatchNorm2d(512)
        self.conv5_1 = nn.Conv2d(512, 512, 1)
        self.conv5_2 = nn.Conv2d(512, 512, 1)
        self.conv5_3 = nn.Conv2d(512, 512, 1)
        self.batch_norm_5 = nn.BatchNorm2d(512)
        self.conv6_1 = nn.Conv2d(512, 512, 1)
        self.conv6_2 = nn.Conv2d(512, 512, 1)
        self.conv6_3 = nn.Conv2d(512, 512, 1)
        self.batch_norm_6 = nn.BatchNorm2d(512)
        self.conv7_1 = nn.Conv2d(512, 256, 1)
        self.conv7_2 = nn.Conv2d(256, 256, 1)
        self.conv7_3 = nn.Conv2d(256, 256, 1)
        self.batch_norm_7 = nn.BatchNorm2d(256)
        self.conv8_1 = nn.Conv2d(256, 128, 1)
        self.conv8_2 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, 1, 1) 
        self.conv8_3 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, 1)

        
        #define forward pass
    def forward(self, x):
        # Pass data through conv1_1
        x = self.conv1_1(x)
        # Use the rectified-linear activation function over x
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.conv1_2(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        #batch normalization
        x = self.batch_norm_1(x)
        x = self.conv2_1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.conv2_2(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        #batch normalization
        x = self.batch_norm_2(x)
        x = self.conv3_1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.conv3_2(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.conv3_3(x)
        #batch normalization
        x = self.batch_norm_3(x)
        x = self.conv4_1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.conv4_2(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.conv4_3(x)
        #batch normalization
        x = self.batch_norm_4(x)
        x = self.conv5_1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.conv5_2(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.conv5_3(x)
        #batch normalization
        x = self.batch_norm_5(x)
        x = self.conv6_1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.conv6_2(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.conv6_3(x)
        #batch normalization
        x = self.batch_norm_6(x)
        x = self.conv7_1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.conv7_2(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.conv7_3(x)
        #batch normalization
        x = self.batch_norm_7(x)
        x = self.conv8_1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.conv8_2(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.conv8_3(x)
        return x
    
    
model = Net()
optimizer = Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.07)
# defining the loss function
criterion = CrossEntropyLoss()

# checking if GPU is available
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    model = model.cuda()
    criterion = criterion.cuda()
    #labels und output des netzwerks in criterion
      
    
def train(epoch):
    model.train()
    train_loss = 0
    
    # train the model
    model.train() # prep model for training
    for data, label in train_loader:
        data = data.to('cuda')
        label = label.to('cuda')
        print(label.size())
        # clear the gradients of all optimized variables
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        #forward pass: compute predicted outputs by passing inputs to the model
        output = model(data)
        # calculate the loss
    
        label = label.long() #convert label to long since in criterion long is expected
        loss = criterion(output, label) #l value is data, ab values are labels
        # backward pass: compute gradient of the loss with respect to model parameters
        loss.backward()
        # perform a single optimization step (parameter update)
        optimizer.step()
        # update running training loss
        train_loss += loss.item() * data.size(0)
    
    
    # calculate average loss over an epoch
    train_loss = train_loss / len(train_loader.sampler)
   
    # printing the loss
    print('Epoch : ', epoch+1, '\t', 'loss :', train_loss)
        
    
# defining number of epochs 
n_epochs = 1

# empty list to store training losses (actually not used)
train_losses = []

# training the model
for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    train(epoch)
```

and here the Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-c26ffccd8f7e> in <module>
    250 # training the model
    251 for epoch in range(n_epochs):
--> 252     train(epoch)

<ipython-input-25-c26ffccd8f7e> in train(epoch)
    224         label = label.long() #convert label to long since in criterion long is expected
    225         print(label.size())
--> 226         loss = criterion(output, label) #l value is data, ab values are labels
    227         # backward pass: compute gradient of the loss with respect to model parameters
    228         loss.backward()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    726         else:
--> 727             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    728         for hook in itertools.chain(
    729                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py in forward(self, input, target)
    960     def forward(self, input: Tensor, target: Tensor) -> Tensor:
    961         return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
--> 962                                ignore_index=self.ignore_index, reduction=self.reduction)
    963 
    964 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py in cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction)
   2466     if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
   2467         reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 2468     return nll_loss(log_softmax(input, 1), target, weight, None, ignore_index, None, reduction)
   2469 
   2470 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py in nll_loss(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction)
   2264         ret = torch._C._nn.nll_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)
   2265     elif dim == 4:
-> 2266         ret = torch._C._nn.nll_loss2d(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)
   2267     else:
   2268         # dim == 3 or dim > 4

RuntimeError: 1only batches of spatial targets supported (3D tensors) but got targets of size: : [1, 2, 64, 64]
```

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using `CrossEntropyLoss()` for this task?
Why does your network outputs 128dim "pixels"?
What are the *spatial* dimensions of your prediction vs the targets?
You are using only 1x1 kernels, meaning your model makes its predictions for each pixel *independantly* of its neighbors. How do you expect it to learn to predict meaningful colorizations?

You should go back to the drawing table and rethink your model and your criterion. Right now this error is the least of your worries.

Comment: 1. In the original network, they used CrossEntropyLoss too, so thats what I did too, at least they mention that after the final layer (conv8_3), they imposed a 1x1 conv layer and a 'cross-entropy loss layer'. So I guessed I could use this loss function too.

2. The error in the output is true. I added this line "self.conv_1x1 = nn.Conv2d(128,2, 1)" right after the conv8_3 layer tue return an output with 2 channels. This, because I want to return for every input "L" value two "a,b" values.

Comment: @Janosch to what task did they employ cross entripy loss?

Comment: they used it for  a multimodal classification task.. they quantified to input (l) values corresponding a, b values and used CrossEntropyLoss to classify their results. 
But thank you, I just switched my loss function to BCEWithLogitsLoss()-function and now my code gets executed whithout throwing an error.... I still need to check results but running without an error is a good first step!